# How to specify an interval of different columns?

Tags: c#, epplus

Suppose that I need to check a value of each cell of a an unknow number of rows of these columns: `H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y`, is possible tell to `Epplus` to evaluate the of each columns starting from row 2?

What I did:

```
 var address = new ExcelAddress("H2:Y2");
            var condition = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(address);
            condition.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Red;
            condition.Formula = string.Format("IF(H2 < 25, 1, 0)", 1);
```

this working only for the column of the second row, I need to check all column indicated above and all rows available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use only the column letters `H:Y`, like this:

```
var address = new ExcelAddress("H:Y");
var condition = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(address);
condition.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Red;
condition.Formula = string.Format("IF(H2 < 25, 1, 0)", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, you know how to setup a condition that check if the value is inside a range like 25 to 40? thanks